# Equation for 3D Curve at Height (See Diagram)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

[image: Visual of Curve at Height]

I have no problem finding a point from a height with zero roll. That's just a 2-Dimensional, simple Trig problem.

My issue comes when you start increasing, or decreasing the roll value while maintaining the same pitch value.  I took some time to draw a visual that describes the issue I'm having.

To sum up the issue, I'm looking for a point on the Z=0 plane at a given location, height, with variable roll and pitch values. As a note, I drew it at the origin with the minimum along the y-axis. The location, altitude, roll and pitch values can change.

Comment: the image is too tiny to read something in it.

Comment: Right-click and open the image in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

The ray through $(0, 0, h)$ making pitch angle $\theta$ from the $z$-axis in the $(x, z)$-plane and making roll angle $\phi$ from the $(x, z)$-plane (measured clockwise about the $z$-axis, as in your diagrams) consists of points of the form
$$
(0, 0, h) + t(\sin\theta \cos\phi, -\sin\theta \sin\phi, -\cos\theta),
$$
and hits the plane $z = 0$ where $h - t\cos\theta = 0$, i.e., $t = h\sec\theta$. The coordinates of the point you seek are
$$
h\tan\theta (\cos\phi, -\sin\phi, 0).
$$
The set of points of pitch $20°$ or pitch $30°$, with roll running from $-88°$ to $88°$ is shown.

[image: Points of fixed pitch angle, variable roll]